# Connecting to remote server

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, odbc

I have a windows server on domainindia.org. I have created one user for mysql and I am trying to connect to MySQL using the following connection string in c#.

```
 Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};Server=IPaddress;Database=db1;User=user;Password=password; Option=3;
```

I am unable to connect. Can someone tell me what may be the problem in this connection string?
The same connection string is working in my local.

I tried to grant permission for that but does not allows me to execute the query.

Can any one tell me how can I connect to my server?

Here is my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
 For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
 http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
 -->
<configuration>

<connectionStrings>

<add name="dbConnection" connectionString= "Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};Server=IPadress;Database=db1;User=Myuser;Password=myPassword;Option=3;"/>


  </connectionStrings> 
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
</system.web>
  </configuration>
```

Comment: Are you sure that the server accepts remote connections. Some hosting server does not accept remote connections and someone else yes but you have to define that when you create the db.

Comment: @FeliceM  that i am not sure in server there is a provision to create odbc connection through that i retrieved connection string. that i have pasted in my web code which is there in same server as well as in my local. both are not working

Comment: show your web.config file.

Comment: @FeliceM here is my web.config file